# Access Angular 2 routes in express app

Tags: node.js, angular, routes

I have created a web app with server side built on node and client side on Angular.File structure is as follow.

```
|_ api
|_ client
|_ config
|_ models
|_ package.json
|_ server.js
```

How ever when I run the server I can only access index page all other routes (angular routes) are not accessible.

Comment: 1- why do you need the route at all ? 2- you can read and pares the route config file. Can you future explain your situation that we could help.

Comment: Okay this is my blog till now built using only node.
geekclan.herokuapp.com 
it has to routes /search and /post. Now I have converted the server side to a restful api and client side to angular 2. I don't understand hot to integrate both  @Mehari

Comment: It should be a wildcard route on server side. Every url (with the exception of `/api/...`) should respond with `index.html`.

Comment: @Ahmad Abdullah, I see if you are developing SPA(single page application), you most likely don't need the route information on server side.
There is  a dedicated router module @angular/router to do routing in client side. so you just provide your data from the server side using REST, and you can create any route you want from angular. this link https://scotch.io/tutorials/routing-angular-2-single-page-apps-with-the-component-router  might help on introduction to angular route.

Comment: if you still don't get it , contact me personally I will help on what I know.

Comment: @Mehari can I have chat with you on skype or anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In an **SPA**(Single page application) , either all necessary code – HTML,JavaScript, and CSS – is retrieved with a single page load, or the
>   appropriate resources are dynamically loaded and added to the page as
>   necessary, usually in response to user actions. The page does not
>   reload at any point in the process, nor does control transfer to
>   another page, although the location hash or the HTML5 History API can
>   be used to provide the perception and navigability of separate logical
>   pages in the application.

angular2 have a dedicated routing module **@angular/router** to do routing on Clinet side, so you most likely don't need routing logic on server side unless you have custom architecture/use case.